# Modify ACF value inside wordpress admin custom post type edit page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I would like to add a custom value that is shown inside an edit post &action=edit in wordpress which is a custom post type.

Comment: In group settings you have rules. Add rule Post type -> is equal -> select the post type.